# Median of the row of an array Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm looking to find the median of just a specific row of an m x n array. I couldn't find anything useful in the Matlab help section. E.g. if I had a small array

```
  [1 2 4; 2 3 4; 6 2 8]
```

how would I find the median of row 2? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for `median` in google or matlab (`doc median`) and you will find the [`median`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) function.

If you want to find the median of row 2, just use `row,column` indexing syntax, where `:` means all entries:

```
A = [1 2 4; 2 3 4; 6 2 8]; 
median(A(2,:))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use:

```
A = [1 2 4; 2 3 4; 6 2 8];

medianRows = median(A, 2); % to find every rows' median

medianRows(2)
```

Or:

```
medianRow2 = median(A(2, :)); % every column of 2nd row
```

Comment: I tried median(A,2) for my array, I was expecting a scalar output but it returned a result as big as my array!

Comment: @MikeMiller Indexing is a very basic concept in MATLAB. [This link](http://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) could help you out in future.

Comment: @Divakar thanks, I did know this, just wasn't sure of the syntax for using the function.

Comment: @MikeMiller `doc function_name` always helps!

Comment: @Divakar Thanks, another nugget I didn't know! I've gone from mainly using Maple to Matlab - it's quite a lot different than I expected!